# Search logs from the excel column

Tags: linux

I have a mysql report that is generated. I will have to search the catalina logs from the phone numbers in the mysql report and display all the information in a excel sheet. So here is the how it needs to be

1. Start with the first phone number in excel sheet
2. Search for the phone number in the logs.
3. Export all search appending to an excel sheet and continue to the next phone number?

Any suggestions how to do this?

I have 500 rows of phone numbers.If I grep 1234567891.The log file looks something like

```
2015-12-23 20:06:05 INFO  Thread-16 XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.Service - Caching location for person max:1234567891 as : 38.802710000000005,-77.63644000000001
```

I will have to search all the 500 phone numbers and get the location of the person .

Comment: This question is pretty high-level; some high-level guidance - try to get the necessary data out of your Excel sheet into a format that Linux can use. Then, try some `grep` commands to get the desired output. Create a CSV format in Linux so that Excel can read it back in.

Comment: @jeff schaller. Any idea how to search to 500 rows one after the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to provide actual code without seeing the data format, but here's what I would do. If you can post more details like sample input and expected output, better responses can be given.

1. First, convert the excels to csv or any other delimited text file that can be read on Unix. You'll probably have to do this before bringing the file to Unix environment.
2. Use `awk` to extract the phone number from the column and `grep` to query the log file for the lines containing that phone number.

   `grep -f <( awk -F, '{print $n}' filename.csv) logfilename >> outputfile`

Something like this should work. In `$n` replace `n` with the column number of your phone number data.

Comment: Please see the edited question

Comment: This should work as long as you substitute the column number in the `awk` part. `awk` (and even `grep`) will automatically go line by line for your entire file, so you don't need to worry about looping over lines. try going through a simple online tutorial about these 2 commands to understand how they work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer .grep -f <( awk -F, '{print $c}' /home/user/file.csv)*  >> output1.csv ----- I am trying to do this, but seem slike I dont get any output. It just keeps thinking. The file is being created, but no data.  Any idea if I was doing right?

Comment: `grep -f <( awk -F, '{print $3}' /home/user/file.csv) ./* >> output1.csv` There's no $c in awk, you have to provide a number for the column. I'm assuming it is 3 since column C in excel is third column. Also, you need a space between the ) and the `*`. I prefer to use ./* just so it is clearer to read.

Comment: Its works. Seems like there was some spaces in the csv file which caused th problem. Thanks